# Get request to twitter API using Ruby, REST

Tags: ruby, json, api, rest, twitter

I try to learn REST in Ruby using Twitter API.

According https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends I have to write GET request to http://api.twitter.com/1/trends.json.

My Ruby code is:

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'rest-client'
 require 'json'

 url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends.json'
 response = RestClient.get(url)

 puts response.body
```

But i'm getting next errors:

```
/home/danik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient  /abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 404 Resource Not Found (RestClient::ResourceNotFound)

from /home/danik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:230:in `process_result'

from /home/danik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:178:in `block in transmit'


from /home/danik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'

from /home/danik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'

from /home/danik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'

from /home/danik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'

from /home/danik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:68:in `get'

from TwitterTrends.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because the resource you are trying to fetch with `http://api.twitter.com/1/trends.json` does not exist, as is explained in this doc [trends docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends)

> This method is deprecated and has been replaced by GET trends/:woeid.
>   Please update your applications with the new endpoint.

You want to fetch a URL like this `https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json`. So, in your code, try doing this:

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'rest-client'
 require 'json'

 url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json'
 response = RestClient.get(url)

 puts response.body
```

And you should get a response.